# if else syntax in ansible playbook

Tags: syntax, ansible

I am new to Ansible and trying to understand what is wrong with my syntax.

My goal is that only one of the roles will be selected. I do **not** want to use 'when'.

Here is what I wrote (I am using Ansible v2.9.5):

```
- name: Install external DB for Cloudera Manager Server
  hosts: db_server
  roles:
 - {{% if (databases_type == "postgresql") %} role: postgresql {% else %} {% endif %}
   {% if (databases_type == "mysql") %} role: mariadb {% else %} {% endif %} 
   {% if (databases_type == "oracle") %} role: oracledb}
```

When I run the playbook I get a syntax error but it is not clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple dictionary might be a cleaner option. For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: Install external DB for Cloudera Manager Server
  hosts: db_server
  vars:
    my_roles:
      postgresql: postgresql
      mysql: mariadb
      oracle: oracledb
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ my_roles[databases_type] }}"
```

---

**Example**

Let's create the roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/postgresql/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: role_name

shell> cat roles/mariadb/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: role_name

shell> cat roles/oracledb/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: role_name
```

Next, let's create an inventory with three servers, group_vars with default *databases_type* and host_vars with the variables for two hosts *test_01* and *test_02*. The third host *test_03* will use the variables from *group_vars*.

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[db_server]
test_01
test_02
test_03

shell> cat group_vars/db_server 
databases_type: mysql

shell> cat host_vars/test_01 
databases_type: postgresql
shell> cat host_vars/test_02
databases_type: oracle
```

Then the playbook gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml 

PLAY [Install external DB for Cloudera Manager Server] *****************

TASK [include_role : {{ my_roles[databases_type] }}] *******************

TASK [postgresql : debug] **********************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  role_name: postgresql

TASK [oracledb : debug] ************************************************
ok: [test_02] => 
  role_name: oracledb

TASK [mariadb : debug] *************************************************
ok: [test_03] => 
  role_name: mariadb
```

Comment: Thanks. For this I get an error: "databases_type is undefined".
In my playbook databases_type in defined under group_vars/all

Comment: Use `include_role`. The variable `databases_type` will be defined when the control-flow reaches `include_role`. I've added an example. The variable `databases_type` must be available before the name of the role is evaluated which is obviously not the case with `roles`. `import_role` won't work either for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is what you are looking for. In the below example, fruit is the variable name. If fruit is equal to Apple then I like it else I do not like it. Let me know if you face any issue or you need more explanation on this.

**If else syntax:**

```
 - name: "[ If Else Example ]"
            command: "echo {{ 'I like it' if  fruit == 'Apple'  else 'I do not like it'}}"
            register: if_reg
          - debug:
                  msg: "{{ if_reg.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have double curly bracket:

```
- {{% if ...
```

Try removing it to make single curly bracket:

e.g.

```
- {% if ...
```

also last line could remove ending curly bracket and put endif:

```
{% if (databases_type == "oracle") %} role: oracledb {% endif %}
```